# How to override native resources?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-application

I'm trying to create custom resource to extend existing zf resources.
It works fine if I choose a different like 'Myrouter' as resource name but if I try to override Router it doesn't work.

Here is my configs.ini (partial)

```
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "Mlo_"
autoloaderNamespaces[] = "My_"
pluginPaths.Mlo_Application_Resource = APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library/Mlo/Application/Resource"
resources.router.defaultTranslator = "Zend_Translate"
```

My file is in APPLICATION . "/../library/Mlo/Application/Resource/Router.php
And named Mlo_Application_Resource_Router.php

Any ideas ?

Comment: Whats your reason to override Zend Frameworks resource plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Zend Framework does this by default so the problem would be your config. Heres what I have in mine:

```
pluginPaths.H2_Application_Resource = "H2/Application/Resource"
```

If your include path is setup correctly try just a relative path.